# Why am I getting Errno 13 Error while saving the file?

Tags: python, errno

Here I am getting Errno 13 Permission error when I'm trying to save the file. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def PlotResults( self , data_dir ):

    outpath = os.path.dirname(data_dir)
    def SaveAndClose(name, counter):
        savefig('%s/%s' % (outpath, name))
        stdprint('Figure "%s" saved -- %s/23 --' % (name, counter))
        close()

    figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27))
    suptitle ( 'Norm of residuals' )
    xlabel ( 'Number of iterations' )
    #hold (True)
    semilogy ( self.residual.T )
    semilogy(ones(self.residual.shape[1])*5, 'bv-')  # soft limit
    semilogy(ones(self.residual.shape[1])*8, 'rv-')  # hard limit

    grid(True, which = "both")

    SaveAndClose('Norm_of_residuals.png', 18)
```

Comment: Because you don't have permission to write that file?  You need to first consider the obvious answer, and if you have done so, explain here what you did.

Comment: Yes. I have been using that code just fine. But all of a sudden it's giving me that error. How can I get permission to that file? Sorry if that's a stupid question but I'm new.

Comment: What operating system? Linux?  What does the command ```ls -l``` tell you about the mode (permissions) and ownership of the file?

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu. When I do ls -l it shows that the file is gives me this

-rw-rw---- 1 minamulhaq minamulhaq  16034 Oct 12 19:21 Calibration.py

Comment: If you are user minamulhaq then you have read-write permission to that file, otherwise you don't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the script execution.

Look at the function:
`def PlotResults( self , data_dir ):`
It takes some path as argument.

I was executing the script and passing some data file as command line argument.

The script is amusing that the data file is passed with directory and it was saving the path in the variable.

The problem was solved when I passed the data file with the directory like:

`python python_script.py ./Data_file.txt`

If passed it without the directory like:

`python python_script.py Data_file.txt`

I was not able to save it.